# discriminator [url] does not have fixed value, binding or existence assertions

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi

Given a profile that references an extension via URL as usual (IOW, 'sliced' by extension URL), if the definition of the extension does not include a `fixedUri` constraint then the HAPI validator (5.6.26) emits the following error:

```
Slicing cannot be evaluated: Could not match discriminator ([url]) for slice [...]
in profile [...] - the discriminator [url] does not have fixed value, binding or 
existence assertions.
```

This seems exceedingly odd, since `Extension.url` is a mandatory field and as such has an implicit 'existence assertion'. Moreover, one would think that - [by definition](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/extensibility.html) - it would have the fixed value specified in `StructureDefinition.url` for a top-level extension.

Note: the problem can easily be prevented by adding the aforementioned `fixedUri` definition to the extension profile, if there is the remotest chance that the extension might ever be involved in slicing by URL (repeating the URL specified in `StructureDefinition.url`).

```json
{
    "id": "Extension.url",
    "path": "Extension.url",
    "fixedUri": "https://foo/StructureDefinition/blah"
}
```

However, I would like to understand what is going on here. Can some shed light on this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "by definition".  It's actually possible to have an extension whose canonical URL differs from the Extension.url - if you're creating a profile of an existing extension.  The Extension data type does, however explicitly pre-define the slicing which is what requires url to be explicitly declared as a fixed value.  In short, everything is functioning as intended.  If you're defining a profile with a base of 'Extension', you'll have to define a fixedUrl.

Comment: My head swims. I thought `Extension.url` was the only means of identifying an extension (because that's what the definition said unto me). I also thought that profiling an extension results in a completely new, different extension (because it has a new URL) and the base extension merely bequeathes its contents to the derived extension without establishing an 'is-a' relationship between the two. Could you please sketch a minimal example, so that we can see which URL goes where in a derived extension instance? Wouldn't `fixedUri` then preclude the creation of derived extension profiles?

Comment: Please point out were the following argument goes wrong: "`Extension.url` is the only place where we can stick a URL to indicate what this extension is supposed to be, and this URL uniquely identifies the extension definition (and hence must have the same value as `StructureDefinition.url` of that definition *per definitionem*)."

Comment: Another formulation of the argument that must be wrong somewhere: "`StructureDefinition.url` specifies the URL that uniquely identifies the definition and which is used as a key for fetching that definition (ignoring the effect of `StructureDefinition.version` for the moment). `Extension.url` specifies the URL that identifies the extension definition and it is the key for fetching said definition. Hence `Extension.url` and the `StructureDefinition.url` of the fetched definition must necessarily always be one and the same."

Comment: Extension.url will be the StructureDefinition.url of the profile that defines the semantics of the extension.  However, subsequent StructureDefinitions (with their own urls) can constrain the value of the extension for their own particular purposes.  If those new URLs are referenced in the element.type.profile of an extension, then those new "tighter" constraints come into force.  The extension.url would, however, remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm always learning new things from you! ;-) Do you have a link to some example of `element.type.profile`? Also, I think we're getting really close to the heart of the matter. If, as you say, `Extension.url` remains the same even in the situation you described, then why the need for a `fixedUri` that restates the contents of `Extension.url`?

Comment: element.type.profile can be seen here: https://build.fhir.org/familymemberhistory-genetic.html.  I don't think there's an example in core where there's an extension that's both defined and then constrained.

The fixedUri is necessary for slicing to work where the extension is used.  There may be multiple extensions referenced by a profile.  Each one of those must differentiate itself, and the way extensions are required to distinguish themselves (because of the slicing rules declared in core) is the value of the `url` element.